# JQuery form submit works randomly

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, magento

I have following set of Javascript/jQuery sprint to handle a form submit:

```
     $('#addtocart').click(function (e){

        // No Accessories: normal submit
        if ($('#accessories ul li').size()==0) {
            $('#quickbuyform').submit();
            return true;
        }
        strName = "<?php echo $_product->getName() ?>";

        // Pop with loading
        popAccessories();
        $('.pop_accessories_area_button').show();$('.pop_accessories_area_button').show();
        e.preventDefault();
    });


    $('#nothanks').click( function (){
        $('#quickbuyform').unbind('submit').submit();
    });

    $('.aceimg').click( function (){    
        $('#quickbuyform').unbind('submit').submit();
    });
```

Requirement:
So as you can see when `addtocart` is clicked it checks if any matching accessories are there for this particular product. If not, just submit the form. If there are accessories then a `div` section appears as a popup. From that popup, if the user clicks on any of the accessory products, then it should submit the `quickbuyform`.

Issue: Now the form submission has become so random. Sometimes it submits the form, while other times it does not.

HELP: Can any one see, what I'm doing wrong here...?

Thanx

Comment: please give us a link to a page where we can see what's going on

Comment: actually the reason I use unbind, coz once I used e.preventDefault(), submit didnt work. But after that I hve done so many changes. Not sure I really want to unbind now.

Comment: http://www.impressiveinvitations.com.au/christening-invitations/little-birdie-square-w-magnet-in-lolly-blue-invitation.html This is my live site, Please click on Upload Tab to locate the "Add to Cart" button. This is the correct one

Comment: one of the reasons why you are having a problem is because when a user clicks on an accessory '.aceimg' it first runs the <a> link that is within the DIV (not giving a chance for the JS to run.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what seems to be the problem:

Inside your `<div class="aceimg>` you have an `<a href="some-product-link.html">`

In effect the browser starts going to the link in the `<a>` tag before evaluating your JQuery.

What you can do is remove the link (since it's just meant to select an accessory and not to view it).

Let us know if you need any further assistance.

Comment: No the thing is when a user select a accessory, current product should add to the cart and user will be taken to the accessory product page. Thats why I have the <a href>. I tried window.location, didnt work

Comment: how does your system handle both of these tasks (adding to cart AND sending to product page) simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that could be going wrong here, especially intermittently:

- If $_product->getName() is not set or throws an error in PHP for
  whatever reason it will put the error message (including HTML
  formatting) into the value of strName depending on your server
  configuration. This will often break the js and cause it to stop working. Check your error console for syntax error messages.

Why do you
   need to do this twice:

> $('.pop_accessories_area_button').show();$('.pop_accessories_area_button').show();

and this:

> > $('#quickbuyform').unbind('submit').submit();

instead of
   this:

> $('#quickbuyform').submit();

This indicates that you may have
   more than one of these forms on the page at once and you are trying
   to work around it.  You may be submitting the invisible form instead of the one that you intend to, etc.

This is not really a solution, I would have to see more of what you are looking at, but I have run into the situations above.

I just checked and you also have a 404 error here:

http://www.impressiveinvitations.com.au/skin/frontend/dreamday/imtheme/js/jquery.form.js

That may have something to do with it...